# Callbacks for AWS EBS Backups or Snapshots

Tags: amazon-web-services, backup

I want to make a backup of several EBS volumes attached to a EC2. There are Snapshots and AWS Backups available.

Issue is, before I can do a backup, I must execute a special script to freeze my application.

Why: it's somewhat im-memory, so this call forces all writes to disk to comlpete and also prevents new disk writes for a duration of a backup.

Is there a way to  execute an arbitrary bash script before the backup job/snapshot?

Comment: Are you using the CLI? API? Any specific SDK?

Comment: I'm using boto3 python api

Comment: Bash to be run before Python script creates the backup? Can you not do both as Python or both as bash?

Comment: Control script is on a different server. And anyway, the idea is automated backups - I create a schedule (using AWS Backup) and AWS creates backups on that schedule. The only issue is before (and possibly after) every backup I need to run a script on a target ec2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no native `--pre-snapshot-script` option for creating an EBS snapshot.

However, you could use a Lambda function, that is triggered based on a scheduled EventBridge rule, to trigger a script to be run before you then programmatically take the EBS snapshot. You'd need the SSM agent to be installed on your EC2 instance(s).

The idea is to use `ssm:SendCommand` and the `AWS-RunShellScript` managed document to run Linux shell commands on your EC2 instance(s).

You have a couple of options, specifically:

1. if you want to inline all of your 'special script' in your Lambda function, *or* download it from S3 during your user data script, *or* manually transfer it *or* ...
2. if you can run the Boto3 `create_snapshot()` (or the AWS CLI [`ec2 create-snapshot`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/create-snapshot.html) command) as part of your 'special script'. If not & you want to do it separately after doing `send_command`, you will also have to use the Boto3 [`ssm.get_command_invocation`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.get_command_invocation) (or the AWS CLI [`ssm get-command-invocation`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ssm/get-command-invocation.html) command) to poll+wait for the command to finish, before you create your snapshot

What you decide to do is dependent on your specific requirements and how much infrastructure you want to manage, but the essence remains the same.

This could be a good starting point:

```py
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ssm = boto3.client('ssm')

    commands = ["echo 'Command xxxxx of special script'"]

    commands.append("aws ec2 create-snapshot --volume-id vol-yyyyy")

    ssm.send_command(
        InstanceIds=['i-zzzzz'],
        DocumentName='AWS-RunShellScript',
        Parameters={'commands': commands}
    )
```